# Unreal Engine Import Warning "The following bones are missing from the bind pose"

Tags: unreal-engine5, fbx, skeletal-animation, skeletal-mesh, unreal

## Problem

I'm receiving the following message while importing the character from mixamo.com. It does not happen for all characters but in some of them.

> The following bones are missing from the bind pose:
>
> mixamorig:HeadTop_End
> mixamorig:LeftHandThumb4
> mixamorig:LeftHandIndex4
> mixamorig:LeftHandMiddle4
> mixamorig:LeftHandRing4
> mixamorig:LeftHandPinky4
> mixamorig:RightHandThumb4
> mixamorig:RightHandIndex4
> mixamorig:RightHandMiddle4
> mixamorig:RightHandRing4
> mixamorig:RightHandPinky4
> mixamorig:LeftToe_End
> mixamorig:RightToe_End
>
> This can happen for bones that are not vert-weighted. If they are not
> in the correct orientation after importing, please set the "Use T0 as
> ref pose" option or add them to the bind pose and reimport the
> skeletal mesh.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

- The Error is general
- I've seen other people receiving the same message for their case as well
- The bone names can be changed depending on the skeleton

To solve this, you just need to select the:

**Use T0 as ref pose**

option while you're importing the FBX file. That will import flawlessly!

ℹ️ By the way "Use T0 as ref pose" option is under the Advanced section.

[image: Use T0 as ref pose]